# git install LAN on ubuntu server and windows LAN

Tags: windows, eclipse, git, ubuntu, lan

I want to install Git on ubuntu machine as a git_server and users in the LAN are windows machines (using eclipse for development) how can i configure my lan ?

Comment: What GIT server are you going to use?

Answer (score 1):

## Setting up LAN

The most easiest thing to do is keep all machines using DHCP to automate the developers configuration on the network. You could then setup the Git server to have an important IP address. *Assuming* the windows machines are setup to use an IP range of 255 starting at .1; you could either...

1. Setup important servers on the other end of the spectrum (.254 git server, 253 printers, etc)
2. Make sure that the lowest spectrum is used first (.1 DHCP, DNS, routing, etc and .2 for git server) and optionally reconfigure the DHCP to start at a higher address.
3. Use a locally-known DNS address that can be well remembered by developers. Typically done by adding a [static route](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes) in the router or by adding the DNS as part of all the developers [hosts file](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/)
4. [Reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) the server that is available locally to be made available by subdomain (e.g. developers.example.com, or git.example.com)

## Setting up a Git Server

Using [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) you can setup repositories the same as GitHub. You can also setup your own accounts online for private repositories than paying for a GitHub subscription. However, the best way to privatise your code is to download GitLab for a server and set it up. Which means better user-management and customisation. If you're familiar with GitHub; GitLab should be quite easy to navigate.

[Start the installation process - https://about.gitlab.com/installation/](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/)

[Install from source using Debian/Ubuntu](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/installation.html)

## Setting up Developer Workstations

Developers may be more interested to use a GUI and I've heard [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) can be quite useful (especially when it comes to merging branches/tags).

Otherwise, if your developers are a little more adventurous and would like to use the command line (e.g. git on Linux), then your developers might find git-scm to be the tool for the job.

https://git-scm.com/downloads